# Why does passing an argument to new Date() result in a different timezone than not passing any argument?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

- When using `new Date(0)` (or any other argument) I get a date in GMT+1
- When using `new Date()` I get a date in GMT+2

[image: screenshot of console]

Why?

Comment: *"(or any other argument)"* What about `new Date(Date.now())` ? The code seems to run on a machine that use summer time, that's why you get GMT+2 for the current time. However, you probably don't have summer time in January, that's why `new Date(0)` shows GMT+1.

Comment: Your assertions are incorrect. the `Date()` constructor works correctly. This happens because of inconsistencies with browser and platform implementations.  What OS and browser pls? What is your platform Locale setting pls. What is your browsers TZ settings pls. What do you get with `new Date(0).toUTCString()`?

Comment: @FelixKling, specifically, January 1970.

Comment: `Date` objects do not have a timezone. The timezone is your local one, and is applied when using `.toString()` only. Looks like you have a DST on one date but not on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely because your locale settings use a time zone that observes daylight savings (or some similar annual time adjustment).

For example, in the Central Time Zone, today is October 19, 2018 and `new Date()` returns (at the moment):

> Fri Oct 19 2018 15:16:16 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

But `new Date(0)`, in the Central Time Zone, returns:

> Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

*Note that both the offset and time zones are different* because December 31, 1969 was during the part of the year that the Central Time Zone observes Central Standard Time while October 19, 2018 is during the part of the year when the Central Time Zone observes Central Daylight Time.

IMPORTANT NOTE:

As pointed out in the comment from [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), `Date` objects do not contain any timezone information. From the [JavaScript Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
>   milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

When a date is represented as a string, i.e. `console.log(new Date())`, the `toString()` method is automatically called and applies an implementation dependent string format to the date that includes a timezone offset and sometimes a timezone name.